# HDMI audio not working on archlinux with pulseaudio

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, hdmi

I can't get working HDMI audio.
And i can't get through this.

What I have:

```
#aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lspci -v:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: None
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at f7c14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f7c1f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at f7c1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8576
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f7c10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: de200000-de3fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000de400000-00000000de5fffff [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: None
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 15
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: None
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7c1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B85 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7c1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at f7c19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 15
    Bus: primary=04, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: None
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

pacmd list-cards

```
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7c14000 irq 35"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0c0c"
        device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 33"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 700, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 760, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 860, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

pacmd list-sinks

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 44649 /  68% / -10.00 dB,   front-right: 44649 /  68% / -10.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC887-VD Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 33"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,10438576,00100302"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

aplay -D plughw: ... does not work on any of the HDMI entries (just in card 0, device 0). it shows no errors, simply it does not make any sound. It works good on Windows 10.

I have pulseaudio.
I've this problem for weeks and I can't find any solution.

Comment: which desktop manager are you using?

Comment: The active card profile for the HDMI card is set to off so you don't get any sink out of it.

Comment: Go to `alsamixer` and press F6 to pick the HDMI card, unmute all controls there, and test with `speaker-test -D hw:HDMI,n -c 2` for n = 3, 7, 8, 9, 10. See which one gives you sound.

Comment: I don't have anything muted. It didn't worked :P

https://k60.kn3.net/1/6/7/C/7/8/2D8.png

Thank you for the answer

Comment: Christopher. None, I'm using i3wm